# How to resolve this problem with an object's collider?

Tags: collision-detection, game-maker

In my game there is an **obj_maze**:

[image]

The width of the maze is 10 pixels in all its extension.

[image]

In the game, the goal is to get the obj_Cube through the maze.

**obj_Cube**:

[image]

The obj_Cube is wider than the maze on purpose, to get a pixel exceeding all sides as the object runs.

[image]

There are also obj_Tubes. They are responsible for defining what position the obj_Cube should go in the intersections that exist in the maze.

[image]

The obj_Tubes also have an extra pixel to stand out from the maze.

[image]

I made this whole explanation, to make it easier to understand my problem.

When obj_Cube collides with obj_TubeX, its new direction will be defined by what you can imagine.

[image]

It turns out that this is done wrongly, detection happens early in the collision, as expected.

[image]

Stirring in the bounding box, I was able to correct the problem.

[image]

By doing this I get the obj_Cube go right or left correctly.

Now and when the obj_Cube does not come from below, but from the right or from the left? This collision certainly did not happen properly.

Here is an example of the obj_Cube from the right, with the bounding box I used earlier:

[image]

The collision is neither detected.

Believe me, I've tested numerous bounding box possibilities for both obj_TubeX and obj_Cube, so that all cases are resolved, but it's physically impossible.

(At least the way I'm trying)...

I also thought about having three equal sprites from each tube with different bounding boxes, but that would be extremely harder and coarser, making my game weigh a lot more.

Sorry for the bad English, I'm not English speaker. I had to use google translator to translate everything.

**Thank you in advance!!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found to this problem was as follows:

Starting with **obj_TubeX** => I've changed your collision box:

[image]

I also modified the obj_Cube collision box (I passed the collision box to the bottom of obj_Cube.):

[image]

In order for the collision to happen correctly, whatever direction the obj_Cube comes from, just modify the obj_Cube rotation before it collides with the obj_TubeX. See below:

[image]

You can change the rotation of obj_Cube by adding an object that makes this change in rotation in the path between obj_Cube and obj_TubeX.

Comment: This is certainly a convenient and simple solution. I like its simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much cleaner solution. Instead of editing bounding boxes, you can detect a collision with the tube and wait before it turns. 
[image]

At 1, the box sets a timer for x frames. At 2, the timer runs out and the box turns.

Comment: Could you tell me exactly how to do this? The function I could use. I think I can not use a timer because there are cubes with different speed.

Comment: Or just compare positions which will be way easier.

Answer (score 1):

In the collision event add the following code as a wrapper for the turning code:

`if (box.x == other.x && box.y == other.y)//other is the tube being collided against
{
    //insert turning code here
}`

Adjust offsets accordingly.

Basically your issue is that you wanted collision to be a replacement for detecting position, and that will only be the case when you make the collision for both exactly one pixel. You could do that, but I wouldn't recommend it.